# Migrating SalesForce Chatter data to Activity Feeds in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: android-activity, migration, salesforce, feed, microsoft-dynamics

Does anyone have any insight or experience into the feasibility / best approach to migrating Chatter data to Activity Feeds in MS Dynamics CRM 2011 (On-prem)? Would be ideal to be able to re-associate the attachments throughout the feed history.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use an ETL tool like Informatica or something similar that links the Chatter data to the Activity Feeds in MS Dynamics. You, then, have several options to sync the data - real time (not recommended for performance reasons), daily sync (preferably at night), or manual sync.

You can buy a cloud version of the ETL or an on-premise version. Some of the tools that I know of are:

1. Informatica
2. Talend
3. Oracle

List is not arranged in an order of preference.

Anup